# PHP : I want to send json and binary data together by CURL

Tags: php, curl

When I send postdata using curl, I want to send json and binary data together.

```
          $RequestForm = array();
          $RequestForm['snd'] = 'Sender';
          $RequestForm['sndnm'] = 'SenderName';
          $RequestForm['rcvs'] = 'Receivers';

          $binary1 = file_get_contents('./test.pdf');
          $binary2 = file_get_contents('./test.jpg');

          $postbody = array(
            'form' => json_encode($RequestForm),
            'file[0]' => $binary1,
            'file[1]' => $binary2
          );

          curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postbody);
```

I want to enter binary data, not the path to the file.

I looked for various ways, but I couldn't solve them.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should not read the file contens to send file... directly pass the file using @ and realpath... like this

```
$postbody = array(
           'form' => json_encode($RequestForm),
           'file[0]' =>'@'.realpath('test.pdf'),
           'file[1]' => '@'.realpath('test.jpg')
         );
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I am not entering the path to the file that is stored locally. file_get_content() used to make binaries

Comment: its the data that is sent ... not sure what are you trying to achieve here?